# Unit Price Attribute Not Visible in Quickbooks Desktop API

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I don't see the Unit Price attribute available in the Item Class when it comes to QBD. Its available in QBO. I am trying to download and fill a database using the items entered via Quickbooks desktop version. Can someone help please?

How can I get the Unit Price for an item in Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item?

**Extra Information Added after comment by Shivan Raptor** (7-Nov-2013)

I am having a Quickbooks Pro Trial 2014 UK version installed in my computer. I have created a company file and items for the company. When I create an item I can enter a Price to that item. Quickbooks must be saving it somewhere. I need to access it using the Quickbooks API from my .Net application.

I am interested on the stock items here. I am using `Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item` class to access it. Am I using the right class? If you go to the API documentation the Item class has a field called Unit Price but its not listed when you actually check from the .Net application.

**Shivan Raptor wanted the code** (8-Nov-2013)

Given below is the code snippet. If you understand the question properly you would realize it cannot give a run time error because you cannot compile a code if you write it with object attributes that are not exposed. And the compiler error is kind of obvious too:

> ATTRIBUTE_NAME not present in CLASS_NAME

In this case, `ATTRIBUTE_NAME = UnitPrice` and `CLASS_NAME = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item` (this is already there in the first post itself)

The relevant code sample is given below. Its the code behind of an ASP.Net page.

```
            Try
                Dim varItemBL As New BL.ItemManagement

                'Preparing Query
                Dim qbdItemQuery As New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemQuery
                qbdItemQuery.ItemElementName = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemChoiceType4.StartPage
                qbdItemQuery.Item = "1"
                qbdItemQuery.ChunkSize = "10"

                'Quering Quickbooks Desktop
                Dim qbdItems = qbdItemQuery.ExecuteQuery(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item)(context).ToList

                'Synchronising Items from Quickbooks to MyDigiRep
                For i As Integer = 0 To qbdItems.Count - 1
                    Dim varUnitPrice As Decimal

                    'Checking whether Unit Price is entered
                    If qbdItems(i).UnitPrice Is Nothing Then
                        varUnitPrice = 0
                    Else
                        varUnitPrice = qbdItems(i).UnitPrice.Amount

                    End If

                    'Synchronising Item with the MyDigiRep database
                    varItemBL.fnAddItemsAPI(qbdItems(i).Name, "NS", varUnitPrice, _
                                            qbdItems(i).UOMAbbrv, HttpContext.Current.Session("companyID"), _
                                            qbdItems(i).Id.Value)

                Next

                'Updating UI to display synchronisation results
                lblItemSycnStatus.Text = qbdItems.Count & " Item Records Synchronised."

            Catch ex As Exception
                lblItemSycnStatus.Text = "Item Records Synchronisation Failed."

            End Try
```

The version of the `Intuit.Ipp.Data.dll` is **2.1.12.0**

Comment: if QBO is QuickBooks Online, then `QBD != QBO`. Available in QBO does not mean it is available in QBD. In documentation, *Product: QBO Description: The monetary value of the service or product. Product: QBW Description: The monetary value of the service or product.
Not applicable to the following types: Subtotal, Group, Payment. Filterable: QBW* What kind of Item are you writing ?

Comment: I have added some extra information to the question after your comment. Please check and let me know if you need further details. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your codes ? What is the compiler error / runtime error ?

Comment: I have added the code and error information you requested. Also the DLL version. Hope you got everything you need. Looking forward for a solution soon. Thanks for your assistance so far.